# Adding a background to a SKLabelNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I have been trying to add a background around my SKLabelNode, but I can't figure out how to do it programmatically in swift 3. I see some old posts that use .background, but that doesn't work for me.

```
let background = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat((title.frame.size.width)), height:CGFloat((title.frame.size.height)))) 
background.zPosition = -1
background.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 12 * 6, y: self.frame.height / 12 * 11); title.addChild(background)
```

Comment: Please post your code, you have tried so far

Comment: What do you mean with: `Add a background` and `around`? What old posts do suggest to use the `.background` property? What does it mean `doesn't work for me`?

Comment: I want to add a small outline of color around a label.

Comment: @GS. please check my new answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this new code, I think this suited more to your problem

```
    let shape = SKShapeNode()
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x:(label?.frame.origin.x)! - 15, y: (label?.frame.origin.y)! - 15, width: ((label?.frame.size.width)!+30), height: ((label?.frame.size.height)! + 50 )), cornerRadius: 64).cgPath
    shape.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.red
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    shape.lineWidth = 5
    label?.addChild(shape)
```

[image: Layout]

Comment: The background disappears when I add a position to it

Comment: Here's my code:
        let background = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.white,
                                      size: CGSize(width: CGFloat((title.frame.size.width)), height:CGFloat((title.frame.size.height))))
        
        background.zPosition = -1
        background.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 12 * 6, y: self.frame.height / 12 * 11);
        title.addChild(background)

Comment: Try this code. Sorry background.position move the background position.
Also position is used when you need to be adjust it.
If you are happy with my answer please up vote it.

Comment: uh, shouldn't you be adding the label as a child of the background? `background.addChild(label)`

Comment: No, not necessarily. It wont be wrong that way either.
It depend which is declare first and how you want to use it.  For this question, there is no information mention, so in my answer I choose to reply this way.

Comment: It works, but is there any way that I could make it rounded around the label?

Comment: don't forget to use @person... I didn't get notified of your response :)